# check_esx.pl doesn't work

Tags: centos, perl, system-monitoring

I try to execute a shinken plugin: /var/lib/shinken/libexec/check_esx3.pl.
It fails.

```
error CHECK_ESX3.PL CRITICAL - Server version unavailable at 'https://dc-srv03.rthd.intra:443/sdk/vimService.wsdl' at /usr/share/perl5/VMware/VICommon.pm line 726.
```

Line command is:

`/var/lib/shinken/libexec/check_esx3-0.5.pl -H dc-srv03.rthd.intra -u 'xxxxx' -p 'xxxxxxx' -l runtime -s list`

This command gives a list of virtual machines.

In line 726 of VICommon we have:

```
  my $xml_parser = XML::LibXML->new;
  my $result;

  eval { $result = $xml_parser->parse_string($response->content) };
  if ($@) {
     die "Server version unavailable at '$url'";
  }
```

I attemped de reinstall rpm package: perl-XML-LibXML-1.70-5.el6.x86_64 and  perl-libxml-perl-0.08-10.el6.noarch with success.

When i execute the plugins it still fails. 
Can you help me ?
operating system centos 6.7
perl version v5.10.1 
Thanks a lot.

Comment: What is the output of 'curl https: //dc-srv03.rthd.intra:443/sdk/vimService.wsdl' (remove the space)? Does it work?

Comment: sorry yes it's work. With a curl nosecure option (-k)

Comment: curl -k https://172.28.255.6:443/sdk/vimService.wsdl
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!--
   Copyright 2005-2016 VMware, Inc.  All rights reserved.
-->

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's without no secure option (`-k`)

```
curl -k https://172.28.255.6:443/sdk/vimService.wsdl
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!--
   Copyright 2005-2016 VMware, Inc.  All rights reserved.
-->
<definitions targetNamespace="urn:vim25Service"
   xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
   xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
   xmlns:interface="urn:vim25"
>
   <import location="vim.wsdl" namespace="urn:vim25" />
   <service name="VimService">
      <port binding="interface:VimBinding" name="VimPort">
         <soap:address location="https://localhost/sdk/vimService" />
      </port>
   </service>
</definitions>
```